# Anaconda new environment with tensorflow 1.14 version

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, version, conda

I have a conda env with tensorflow 2.2.0 But now I want to create a new env with tensorflow 1.14.0.

I used `conda create --name tensorflow1_14 tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0` to create a new env.

But when I tried checking the tensorflow version in this env it still gives me 2.2.0
and when I use `conda list` it shows the tensorflow-gpu version as 1.14.0

Because of this I cannot use the `tf 1.14.0` Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Follow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I am using Anaconda for virtual env. This link says with pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is wondering what went wrong! here is the solution.

There was an overlap of `pip` and `conda` install. Steps followed:

1. conda uninstall tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
2. pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu==2.2.0
3. conda install tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0